# I/O Completion ports without Threads

Tags: sockets, io-completion-ports

The question is about how to use just one loop to handle all sockets requests inside the main program thread. 
This is possible using WSAEventSelect and WSAWaitForMultipleEvents but we are here restricted to 64 Events.
I could also use WSAAsyncSelect but I would need a window to handle socket messages.

What I do not find is how to make the listening socket also work asynchronously with I/O Completion.
The function GetQueuedCompletionStatus seems to be intended to be used with data transmission but not to handle incoming connecting request.

My idea would be the following:

```
CompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1)
Listen = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)
bind
listen
myData[index]->s = Listen;
CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)Listen, CompletionPort, &myData[index], 1)
index++;

while(TRUE) {
   GetQueuedCompletionStatus(CompletionPort, &BytesTransferred, (LPDWORD)&PerHandleData, (LPOVERLAPPED *)&PerIoData, INFINITE)
   if(PerHandleData->s == Listen) 
       AcceptReq = new socket;
       myData[index]->s = Listen;
       CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)AcceptReq, CompletionPort, &myData[index], 1)
       WSARecv(AcceptReq)
       index++;
   }
   else {
       // Process received/transmitted data
   }
}
```

Is that possible or is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: AcceptEx is the answer, also asynchronous and can be added to the completion port. Very nice example here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Samples\netds\WinSock\iocp